# How to register ImageHandler in web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, handler

I have written the following handler class which is used to read images from database and show them in my web page :

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="Handler" %>

using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web;

public class Handler : IHttpHandler, System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState
{

    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["IranQRDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            string TableName = context.Session["TableToQuery"].ToString();
            string ID = context.Session["ID"].ToString();

            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM " + TableName + " WHERE ID=" + ID, conn);

            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = comm.ExecuteReader();
            dr.Read();
            context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
            context.Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])dr["Image"]);
            conn.Close();

        }
        catch
        {
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM DefaultImage WHERE ID=1", conn);

            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = comm.ExecuteReader();
            dr.Read();
            context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
            context.Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])dr["Image"]);
            conn.Close();
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

This class works fine on my local ! I have uploaded my website and when I query my database all data is returned to my web page except the image is not shown in the image control. I have searched the web and I found out that I should register my handler in the `web.config` file and also IIS version is 7 on the host and It's running in integrated mode ! So I know that I should register that handler in `<System.webserver><Handlers>`  part of the `web.config` .

For more detail I added the handler class to my project root directory and not in the `App_Code` directory ! And I have uploaded the website as precompiled website and I have the precompiled `Handler.ashx` in my root directory and I have `App_Web_handler.ashx.cdcab7d2.dll` file in my `App_Code` .

I also have added :

```
<add name="ImageHandler" verb="*" path="*.jpg" type="Handler" />
```

in my `web.config` file but it still does not work :(

Could any one help please me find the correct registration ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And here comes the answer ! there was nothing wrong with my code , and there was a firewall on the host wich did not allow my images to be showen ! after configuring the firewall my project works just fine :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to map *.jpg to ASPX File handler in the IIS mapping, otherwise it will not work. This link will help you : [How to: Configure an HTTP Handler Extension in IIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb515343.aspx)

Comment: thank you , I will try that , but don't you see anything wrong in my code ?

Comment: You can do few optimizations, and if it is working locally, it should work in production also.

Comment: I mean in <add name="ImageHandler" verb="*" path="*.jpg" type="Handler" /> did'nt you see anything wrong ? and should'nt I map *.jpg to ashx ?

Comment: No I think it is correct only - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227433

Comment: I checked the iis manager , should I do this : In handler mappings I click Add Managed Handler then a dialog pops up ! The name property shoul be the same as name property of the <add> tag in web config and the type is going to be : Hanlder and the Request path is : *.jpg     is it enough ? or I should set request restrictions too ?

Comment: No I don't think it required.